# Issue migrating in Django with South (Mysql)

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south, database-migration

I just had an issue where `south` seems to be confused between two migrations.

**Last (4) migrations:**
[image: imgggggg]

I had a table:

```
class VulnFuzz(models.Model):
    fuzzVector = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    FkToVulnTbl = models.ForeignKey(Vuln)
```

I wanted to change that table to something else:

```
class VulnFizz(models.Model):
    fizzVector = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    FkToVulnTbl = models.ForeignKey(Vuln)
```

The problem is, when I ran:

```
python manage.py schemamigration Scanner --auto
```

it says to then migrate it, so I do using:

```
python manage.py migrate Scanner
```

It says:

```
Migrating forwards to 0041_auto__del_field_vulnfizz_FkToVulnTbl.
 > Scanner:0032_auto__chg_field_vulnfuzz_FkToVulnTbl__del_index_vulnfuzz_FkToVulnTbl
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: DESCRIBE `Scanner_vulnfuzz`
The error was: (1146, "Table 'vulnawarefinal.scanner_vulnfuzz' doesn't exist")
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = CREATE INDEX `Scanner_vulnfuzz_30a95dc2` ON `Scanner_vulnfuzz` (`FkToVulnTbl_id`);
```

I had already tried running the suggestion of before changing tables:

```
CREATE INDEX `Scanner_vulnfuzz_30a95dc2` ON `Scanner_vulnfuzz` (`FkToVulnTbl_id`)
```

But that didnt fix it.

I am at a loss now, how should I go about fixing this? Or should I redo the whole db?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the metadata in the database make it somehow think that 030 migration was already done? Could you check in the database?

Comment: Are you just trying to rename the name of the table?

Comment: No the use of the second table was to just try creating the same table again, but it wouldn't allow me to, because of the first table's problem @PauloBu

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso - see the image, those migrations shown already are in the migrationhistory table (default by south)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're at migration 31 and you want to migrate to 41. The error occurs at migration 32 so the problem is not with your current described code change and the associated migration 41.

Migration 32 expects table `Scanner_vulnfuzz` to be there but it's not. In other words: your database is not in the state that South expects it to be.

You may be able to recover by migrating back to the migration that creates the table and then running all migration again. Otherwise you may have to recreate the database and run `syncdb` and `migrate` again from the beginning.

Comment: You can migrate to a particular migration using: `python manage.py migrate Scanner xxx` where `xxx` is a number.

Comment: So I need to migrate to 30, 31, etc, then 32?

Comment: I don't know. You'd need to migrate back to the migration where the table is created. However it may be that you can't migrate backwards because your database is in an inconsistent state. In that case you may need to start from scratch or manually alter the database.